# Download PDB files for Microsoft Dependencies

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I have some microsoft dependencies added like [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) and other dependencies added via NuGet.

Is there an option to download the PDB files for this from Nuget or should I download them manually ? If so where can I download it from ?

Comment: No, expectation is that you build from the github.com source if you need it.  Also gives you the essential Debug build.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you please let me know how to build it ?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/docs/BuildFromSource.md.